# pipe a list of files to lrztar or lrzip

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe

I know you can pipe the output of a ``find" command to tar, and then that file to lrzip, but I also know that will reduce the compression efficiency. I tried

```
find . -name "*.tex" |lrztar -n -o find.lrztar-n -
```

and

```
find . -name "*.tex" |lrzip -n -o find.lrzip-n -
```

which does not work. I didn't get an error, rather it produced a non-sense file. Is lrztar/lrzip not capable of functioning like this? It doesn't sound like it can from the man pages. It seems as if lrzip is for one file, and lrztar for one directory, as opposed to multiple files.

Comment: Why do you think that would reduce the compression efficiency?

Comment: Taken from the lrzip git page: Piping output to and/or from STDIN and/or STDOUT works fine with both compression and decompression, but larger files compressed this way will likely end up being compressed less efficiently. Decompression doesn't really have any issues with piping, though.

Comment: The documentation I could find said that you could not pipe data to lrzip at all, and instead had to tar up the data first, then run lrzip on the file.

Comment: Their git page says otherwise, and I can confirm that you can indeed pipe tar to lrzip. This was a few days ago, but I believe I also piped lrzip to gpg.